# Is the latest Remmina 1.0 in the official 12.04 repositories?

Tags: 12.04, apt, repository, remmina

I just noticed that the copy of remmina I have on my machine (Running ubuntu 12.04) is 9.99.1 (This is up to date according to apt). The [remmina website](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/) says that the most recent version is version 1.0 which uses FreeRDP. I'd like to use FreeRDP instead of rdesktop because of the improved MS RemoteApp support.

To cut to the chase, is version 1.0 of remmina in the repos, or do I have to install it manually? (I've had a quick browse but haven't found anything).

Edit:

Running `rmadison remmina` returns the following (trimmed to only show the precise repo details)

```
remmina | 1.0.0-1ubuntu5 |       precise | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
remmina | 1.0.0-1ubuntu6.1 | precise-updates | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
```

Which is supposedly the version I have installed, however the "about" dialog says version 0.99. Additionally, `FreeRDP` is not installed on my system, so remmina cannot be at version 1.0.

Added:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, it is - in *main!*

- Remmina 1.0 was released on *February 11, 2012* ([source: Official Homepage](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/))

  - Remmina switched to FreeRDP **since 0.8** (source: [Official Wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/remmina/index.php?title=Main_Page#RDP))
  - The recent "change to FreeRDP" which may have confused you is just their moving to the FreeRDP GitHub for *hosting their source code*
  - RDP support in Remmina is through FreeRDP *only*, via a plugin with the following dependency chain (no FreeRDP binaries are necessary):
    `reminna-plugin-rdp <-- libfreerdp-plugins-standard <-- libfreerdp1`.
  - These libraries are installed automatically when you install Remmina, unless you have disabled the default APT policy of installing recommends, in which case *you will have no RDP support* until you install `remmina-plugin-rdp`!

#### Proof:

- [**Official changelog**](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/remmina/+changelog) for the Ubuntu version in Precise 12.04 says:

```
remmina (1.0.0-1) unstable; urgency=low
  * New upstream release. 
_ Compatible with FreeRDP 1.0 (Closes: #658363).
.
.
.
 -- Luca Falavigna   Sat, 11 Feb 2012 17:28:48 +0100
```

#### To be "precise ;)" the Ubuntu version is *more advanced* than the upstream:

- In fact, the changelog says that a number of *additional improvements* have been done by the Debian/Ubuntu developers since 1.0.0, including:

  1. add clipboard support.
  2. fix smooth scrolling
  3. improved translations
  4. Added Unity Launcher support
  5. App indicator support added
  6. Add -i option to only start as a tray icon.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. Does this mean that remmina doesn't acutally *use* freerdp for the backend? I don't have the package installed so I'm guessing it doesn't?

Comment: It does. RDP support is provided by `reminna-plugin-rdp`, which in turn depends on `libfreerdp-plugins-standard` which in turn depends on `libfreerdp`. The FreeRDP binaries have nothing to do with this, and all the above should be installed unless you disabled the (default) apt policy of installing recommendations. (and RDP support will NOT work in Remmina without that plugin!)

Comment: oh ok, it all makes sense now :D I thought that the `FreeRDP` package itself would have to be installed. Cheers :D

Comment: It won't let me give it to you for another 22 hours :/ I've marked the answer as accepted though, I guess you'll just have to hang in there ;)

Comment: There's your bounty!!

Answer (score 3):

I can't believe no one has mentioned this, so I will. I have had exactly the same issue just now with Remmina.

The command:

```
sudo apt-cache show remmina
```

gives

```
Package: remmina
Priority: optional
Section: gnome
Installed-Size: 362
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Luca Falavigna <dktrkranz@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
**Version: 1.0.0-4ubuntu2**
Replaces: remmina-common (<= 1.0.0-1ubuntu8), remmina-gnome, remmina-xfce
Depends: libappindicator3-1 (>= 0.4.90), libc6 (>= 2.15), libgcrypt11 (>= 1.4.5), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.35.9), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0), libssh-4 (>= 0.3.91), libvte-2.90-9 (>= 1:0.27.2), libx11-6, remmina-common (= 1.0.0-4ubuntu2), dbus-x11
Recommends: remmina-plugin-rdp, remmina-plugin-vnc
Breaks: remmina-common (<= 1.0.0-1ubuntu8), remmina-plugin-data (<= 0.9)
Filename: pool/main/r/remmina/remmina_1.0.0-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
Size: 132012
MD5sum: ca69666bd3ccbdf97f542a2b28c823c6
SHA1: 86f26b764ef4d24c378629b42a30cba2511e75f9
SHA256: 6a58cf5f5a8c53a5285108c4aa07dcc10f31abeaef21cf8c9bc63e2997004d14
Description-en: remote desktop client for GNOME desktop environment
 Remmina is a remote desktop connection client able to display and control a
 remote desktop session.
 .
 It supports multiple network protocols in an integrated and consistant user
 interface. Currently RDP, VNC, NX, XDMCP and SSH protocols are supported.
Homepage: http://remmina.sourceforge.net/
Description-md5: ede6e83246f1eea7dfe2191738034796
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 9m
Task: ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-usb, edubuntu-desktop, edubuntu-usb
```

Which does indeed show that the version installed is =>1.0

apt-cache is a little gem of a command:

```
sudo apt-cache search remmina
```

Will give all packages in the repositories to which you are subscribed that contain the term remmina:

```
remmina - remote desktop client for GNOME desktop environment
remmina-common - common files for remmina remote desktop client
remmina-plugin-rdp - RDP plugin for remmina remote desktop client
remmina-plugin-vnc - VNC plugin for remmina remote desktop client
remmina-plugin-gnome - GNOME plugin for remmina remote desktop client
remmina-plugin-nx - NX plugin for remmina remote desktop client
remmina-plugin-telepathy - Telepathy plugin for remmina remote desktop client
remmina-plugin-xdmcp - XDMCP plugin for remmina remote desktop client
```

The show command will give exact details for any particular package. Very handy.

Comment: Very nice! I've also come across `rmadison`, a utility which tells you the version available in each supported version of Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

It is in the Ubuntu main repository actually:

```
remmina:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.0-1ubuntu6.1
  Version table:
     1.0.0-1ubuntu6.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main i386 Packages
     1.0.0-1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
```

I'm not sure where you got the 9.99.1 number from exactly. Where did you get that version info from?

Comment: version no. came from the about remmina dialog; see the image I added to the question :) also note that after an apt-get update (done before the screenshot) apt thinks remmina is up to date. I don't think it will make any difference but I use amd_64 Ubuntu.

Comment: This appears to be due to the fact that the upstream 1.0.0 release actually has the version defined as 0.9.99.1 in the build system, and thus you see it in the about box. It appears that version number was bumped to 1.0.0 *after* the 1.0.0 release was made.